# Should the 'a' in 'agile/Agile' be capitalized?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

I was discussing this topic in a chat over on [PMSE](https://pm.stackexchange.com/) and figured I'd pose it to the experts.

Should the 'a' in the word 'agile/Agile' be capitalized? Specifically, when referring to the concept brought about by the [Manifesto for Agile Software Development](http://agilemanifesto.org/).

On one hand, the term agile may simply apply to the adjective of agility, which coincidentally is part of the title of the Manifesto for Agile Software Development.

On the other hand, it's feasible that 'Agile' is actually an abbreviation of the 'Manifesto for Agile Software Development'. Similar to how 'Manifesto' would be - the vernacular has merely decided 'Agile' as its abbreviation rather than 'Manifesto', presumably due to less ambiguity. And, as far as I know, the abbreviation of a proper noun ('Manifesto for Agile Software Development') should be capitalized. Of course, it could be argued that 'Agile' is referring to the concept brought about by the Manifesto, rather than the Manifesto itself. If so, should it then be considered a proper noun in its own right, or no?

As requested, some examples (emphasis mine):

> The difficulties with requirements gathering and how they change are one of the reasons for the "**agile** methods."

---

> What mechanisms promote continuous improvement on **Agile** teams?

---

> The term **agile** management is applied to an iterative, incremental method of managing the ...

---

> **Agile** Methodology - Everything you need to need to know -- and do -- to introduce **Agile** testing to your organization.

Comment: Can you supply some examples, from that discussion or elsewhere, where you feel it should be capitalized?

Comment: @curiousdannii Given there was a tag on capitalization, I assumed this would be on-topic. Is there any way I could/should modify it to be so?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be two separate concepts here - the actual "Manifesto for Agile Software Development", and the related class of like management styles and techniques that it is a part of.

The first is a proper noun, so should be capitalized, while the second is an adjective, and so shouldn't be.

i.e:

> What mechanisms promote continuous improvement on Agile teams?

but,

> The term agile management is applied to an iterative, incremental method of managing the ...

Your examples are pretty good in this respect - just keep in mind what exactly the sentence is referring to.